Question about maps on cofibers being zero
I have the following problem, I am skeptical that the solution is as easy as the one I wrote so would be grateful if some expert can enlighten me.
Let $G\colon \mathcal{C}\to \mathcal{D}$ be a functor between stable $\infty$-categories (feel free to put more adjectives if needed) with left adjoint $F$, and let $\phi\colon X\to Y$ a map in $\mathcal{C}$ such that $G(\phi)\simeq 0$ in $\mathcal{D}$. Let $Z$ and $Z’$ be objects in $\mathcal{D}$ and consider a map $\psi\colon F(Z’)\to F(Z)$. Then we have a commutative diagram$$
\newcommand{\ra}[1]{\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\xrightarrow{\quad#1\quad}\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!}
\newcommand{\da}[1]{\left\downarrow{\scriptstyle#1}\vphantom{\displaystyle\int_0^1}\right.}
%
\begin{array}{l}
\mathrm{map}_{\mathcal{C}}(F(Z),X) &\ra{} & \mathrm{map}_{\mathcal{C}}(F(Z'),X) \\
\qquad\da{\mathrm{map}(F(Z),\phi)} && \qquad\da{\mathrm{map}F(Z’),\phi)}  \\
\mathrm{map}_{\mathcal{C}}(F(Z),Y) &\ra{}&\mathrm{map}_{\mathcal{C}}(F(Z’),Y)   \\
\end{array}
$$
By adjunction we have $\mathrm{map}(F(-),\phi)\simeq \mathrm{map}(-,G(\phi))$ therefore the two vertical maps above are homotopic to the zero map. Can I conclude that the map induced on the cofibers $$
\mathrm{map}(\mathrm{Fib}(\psi),\phi) \colon \mathrm{map}_{\mathcal{C}}(\mathrm{Fib}(\psi),X)\to \mathrm{map}_{\mathcal{C}}(\mathrm{Fib}(\psi),Y)
$$
is also equivalent to the zero map? Notice that $\psi$ does not come from a map in $\mathcal{D}$.

I would have to guess the answer is "no". It feels too close to asking something like "is the class of spectra on which $p = 0$ closed under cofibers", for which the answer is definitely no. I guess the map you're looking at should be in some sense nilpotent though.

The answer is no. Here is a counterexample. Let $p$ be a prime.
Let $F = \mathbb Z / p \otimes_{\mathbb Z}^L (-) : D(\mathbb Z) \to D(\mathbb Z)$, and let $\phi = p : \mathbb Z \to \mathbb Z$. Take $Z' = \mathbb Z, Z = \Sigma \mathbb Z$ to be appropriate shifts of $\mathbb Z$ and choose $\psi : \mathbb Z / p \to \Sigma \mathbb Z / p$ so that $Fib(\psi) = \mathbb Z / p^2$ (after all, there is a short exact sequence $0 \to \mathbb Z / p \to \mathbb Z / p^2 \to \mathbb Z / p \to 0$). Since $p = 0$ on $\mathbb Z / p$ -modules, but $p \neq 0$ on $\mathbb Z / p^2$ or its dual, you get a counterexample.

I feel the need to put in a reminder that if we look at $Spectra$ instead of $D(\mathbb Z)$, then we should note that $p = 0$ on $\mathbb S / p$ iff $p$ is odd. On $\mathbb S / 2$ we have $4 = 0$ but $2 \neq 0$. This is related to the fact that $\mathbb S / 2$ does not admit a unital multiplication. In general in a symmetric monoidal stable category with unit $S$, if $\phi : \Sigma^n S \to S$ is an endomorphism-up-to-shift, then $\phi^2 = 0$ on $S / \phi$, but it's often the case that $\phi \neq 0$ on $S / \phi$.

Thank you for the answer, now I understand
